# htaccess block exact domain path request

Tags: .htaccess

i got a huge problem with spam bots in my buddypress community

they check a certain path and slow down the server. the path is

`http://community.netigate.net/discussions/?p=/entry/signin`

how can i block exactly and only this particular request?

because i got a forum which can be accessed at `http://community.netigate.net/answers/discussions`

i tried the following, but i blocked everything containing `"discussions"`

```
RedirectMatch 403 /discussions/
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite. Put this code on top of all code in your main .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=/entry/signin(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^discussions/?$ - [F]
```

Comment: `p=entry/signin` should be `p=/entry/signin`

Comment: thanks anubhava end machineaddict. it works like a charm. kinda tricky with these rules.